# How to include github library to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) library for Floating Action Buttons.I add

```
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
```

to build.gradle as explained in usage and then add the code in xml, but unfortunately for me there is no functionality as expected.
I get no errors just the floating button does not work.

So I start wondering if I should add the code of the library as well, although this makes no sense to me since I add dependency.
Should I add the code to my project and how exactly should I make the connection between the library I added and my source code.

Sorry if this is a simple question, its just first time using such library for me.

Comment: `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton` is this attribute is not working ?

Comment: There is no need to make additional connection, once you added library in build.gradle and app sync successfully completed means android studio downloaded that library and integrated to your project, you may be missing something in your implementation

Comment: well it depends what "working" means. There are no errors when I run it, it just doesn't open any submenu items and is not clickable. It's just a regular floating button

Comment: Library contains Sample app. Just follow the sample .

Comment: sample works perfectly but in it the library is added as part of the project and not by dependency in gradle. So it is not that useful in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "it doesn't work" you mean you don't have access to any of its classes in your code, make sure you also have the [JitPack maven repository](https://jitpack.io/) in your Project-level Gradle build file.

```
// Include repositories here for which dependencies can be retrieved from.
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    // For example:
    // google()
    // jcenter()
}
```

If you do have access to the library in your code, and the library itself is not working as expected, I would check its [github issues](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues) page for help.

As a last resort, you can pull the GitHub repository and compile the library yourself into an [.AAR](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) for your project.

Comment: I have access to the classes but there is no functionality when I add the button to the XML. In the sample provided simply adding the floatingMenu and button to the xml creates click events and opening of the sum menu, but when I add this it is not working. I suspect that it might be android lib version problem or something

Comment: so this actually answers my question. problem seems to be in the library or the usage itself. Thank you for the answers all

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You also need to add the code. Adding

```
`compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
```

only adds the library to your project files. To use it, you have to call it by creating an element in one of your layouts XML file.

**tip**: Whenever you get stuck in a problem like this, simply create a temporary project in Android studio and simply copy and paste all the code to your README.md to your project. Check out what each snippet does and then add that to your main project.

Comment: I saw that I have the library code now in "External libraries". But how to create element in the XML as you said?